# Show json array from local file in html table using Spring boot project

Tags: java, html, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a JSON file with array data, i want to show this data in an HTML table. I am using the Spring boot project structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Movies Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>

<th>Title</th>
<th>Imdb-ID</th>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Rating</th>
<th>Rating-Count</th>

</tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUT5Q.png)

Comment: There are too many options here. Any answer will primarly be opinion based. However here's an example using Jquery and DataTables to poulate a table from JSON: https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-jquery-datatables-a2e816e2b5e9

Comment: A simple way to achieve this is using Spring Boot with template engine (e.g. FreeMarker). Take a look at [Introduction to Using FreeMarker in Spring MVC](https://www.baeldung.com/freemarker-in-spring-mvc-tutorial).